# Choose 1 element per index randomly from list A or B in Python

Tags: python, list, random

I have 2 lists in Python and I want to choose, for every index either an element from list A or list B.

I managed to do it easily but this solution has bad performance and it doesn't seem very elegant.
Can anybody sugest an alternative that doesn't rely in these **for** cycles with **if**'s inside?

I'll post the code here:

```
def scramble(list1, list2):
    finalList = []
    for i in range(32): # the list has 32 elements
        if randint(1,2) == 1:
            finalList.append(list1[i])
        else:
            finalList.append(list2[i])
    return finalList
```

Answer (score 10):

```
import random
from itertools import izip

l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
l2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

[random.choice(pair) for pair in izip(l1, l2)]
# e.g. [0, 1, 'c', 3, 'e', 'f']
```

Comment: Nice. But is it faster, or just nicer looking?

Comment: Well, this looks like it. I'm completely new to Python so I'll test it and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @combatdave: I just timed it and my version is about 3x faster for 2 lists holding 1e6 integers each.

Comment: Well, it works! And it's about 2x as fast. Thank you.
Just one thing. Since list1 and list2 are always of same size, shouldn't I use zip() instead of izip() ?

Comment: @jbssm: `izip` behaves exactly as `zip` on lists of unequal length, i.e. this shouldn't influence your decision. However, `izip` is more efficient here as it doesn't create the whole list of pairs in memory, but creates the pairs one after each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a single list comprehension like so:

```
newList = [x if randint(0,1) else y for x, y in zip(l1, l2)]
```

I'm not certain whether that actually improves performance much, but it's clean.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
def scramble(list1, list2):
    return [random.choice([list1[i], list2[i]]) for i in range(len(list1))]
```

It assumes len(list1)==len(list2). I'm not sure that this would necessarily be any faster though.

Comment: Well, it's much nicer looking, but it takes the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "clever" list comprehension:

```
from random import choice

def scramble(l1,l2):
    length = min(len(l1),len(l2))
    lists = (l1,l2)
    return [choice(lists[i]) for i in xrange(0,length)]
```

Though it's less readable.

Comment: Hi Mark. I think this will take about the same time, perhpas just a bit less, since there is still the for cycle altough it removed if comparisons.

Comment: @jbssm - I did some profiling and changed my code accordingly. This version seems to be a hair faster than mhyfritz's, but I voted for his because it is more elegant and the main performance boost I got was in using choice, rather than randint. If your interested I can add the profiling results to the answer.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I'll keep this answer as well.